# How to quell this C6386: Buffer overrun while writing ... warning? // am 99% certain it is bogus

Tags: pointers, memory, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I am getting the following warning message in Visual Studio C++:

> C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'g_bufferInfos': the writable
> size is 'n*24' bytes, but '48' bytes might be written.

From the code below, I have triple checked and can't see how the code could be a problem; but meanwhile is there a way to clean it up to remove the warning or do I need to use a pragma to disable it?

```
        ASIOBufferInfo*     g_bufferInfos = {};
        
        // ... g_bufferInfos needs to be assigned a variable length array that is
        //     fed to ASIOCreateBuffers(ASIOBufferInfo* info, ...)

        using indices = std::vector<size_t>;

        // ...

        bool    start(const indices ins, const indices outs)
        {
            if (g_bufferInfos)
                return false; // !!!

            size_t n = ins.size() + outs.size();
            g_bufferInfos = new ASIOBufferInfo[n];

            long min, max, pref, gran;
            ASIOGetBufferSize(&min, &max, &pref, &gran);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < ins.size(); ++i)
            {
                g_bufferInfos[i].isInput = true;          // *** C6386 warning here ***
                g_bufferInfos[i].channelNum = ins[i];
            }
            for (size_t i = 0; i < outs.size(); ++i)
            {
                g_bufferInfos[ins.size() + i].isInput = false;
                g_bufferInfos[ins.size() + i].channelNum = outs[i];
            }
            ASIOCreateBuffers(g_bufferInfos, n, pref, &g_callbacks);
            return ASIOStart() == ASE_OK;
        }
```

Comment: is the `size()` method on `indices` marked as const?

Comment: so, assumptions being ins.size() and outs.size() always return the same value, and neither of them are negative, it would work. Compiler can't know that, however.

Comment: sorry forgot about 'indices';  which is just std::vector<size_t> re-badging so am guessing as the argument is const then it should be marking all it's members as such.

Comment: Thanks' Garr I believe you were correct; I substituted all the size() calls for a pair of values assigned at the head of the function and the warning is gone now (refactored a couple of other things at the same time though so can't be 100% certain).